# ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, machine-learning

i need help
I'm working on machine learning.
I tried to import a dataset using this code:

```
    # Importing the libraries
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    # Importing the dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Rural3.csv', low_memory=False)
    X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 77].values

    # Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

    # Feature Scaling
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

However, an error appears: 
ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

What should i do please ? i'm newbie in python.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line was the error?

Comment: There are probably just `np.inf` values in either `X` or `Y` that you need to drop. You can find those values through a filter like `dataset.iloc[dataset.values==np.inf]`

Comment: `X_test = sc.transform(X_test)` should be `X_test = sc.transform(X_test)` or chagne the line above

Comment: thanks so much for answering me, but what should i do exactly ? i didn't get it ?

Comment: @yosemite_k , the errors appears at the feature scaling section .. ?! is that change any thing ?

Answer (score 4):

This solution works well, Fixed the error while power transforming

```
df =df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to see if you have null values, after loading the dataset with pandas do the following:

```
dataset = dataset.dropna()
```

also make sure that your X values are numeric, you can use either dataset.describe() or dataset.info():

```
print(dataset.info()) # will give you info about the dataset columns
```

you can also try to update your sklearn, there is a known bug in certain versions of sklearn (i dont remeber which one)

```
# if you are using conda
conda install scikit-learn 
# if you are using pip
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thank u so much sir for answring me, i applyed the dataset.info function, and as results it gives me that my dataset contains : float64(75), int64(1), object(2).
Knowing that my base contains only numerical values !! what is object dtype ? and how can i deal with this thing ?

Comment: it means you have non numeric values in your dataset. object is a data type that is neither numeric, date time etc. from the dataset.info() we see that you have two features not recognized as numeric now try to do the following `dataset = dataset[dataset.applymap(np.isreal).any(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try normalizing if your data has very large values. You can find more info [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

Comment: i used the function .. but another error appeared .. ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype ('float64') !

Comment: Okay that means that you have null values also. Here is a link to help you better preprocess your data - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/07/practical-guide-data-preprocessing-python-scikit-learn/

Comment: Thanks sir, i tried to normalize, but it's always the same error ! how can i deal  with inf and too large value ? is there any other type of variable larger than float 64 for example ? float 128 that i can use it instead of float 64 ?

Comment: Use min-max normalization to get values between 0 and 1. And replace NaN values with either the mean or the median. If you still get a problem post the output of the data you have preprocess to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This error is quite misleading at times.
if you have blank values in the data set ( which means certain features in the dataset have blank values)even then you can get this type of error.
How do we resolve this ...

1. Covert the dataframe and export them into csv. below is the code "df" is the dataframe
   Dataframe to CSV

```
compression_opts = dict(method='zip',archive_name='out.csv')  
df.to_csv('out.zip', index=False, compression=compression_opts)
```

You can also try this

```
df[df['column_name'] == ''].index
```

2. Identify the features which have blank values by analyzing the output CSV.
3. Remove the complete record which have blank values, through the below code

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['column_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

df_new = df[np.isfinite(df).all(1)]
```

This removes the rows that contain `infinity` or `NaN` values